# How to make middleware error out and not go to next middleware/handler

Tags: go, middleware, go-chi

What I am trying to achieve is the following: I have my own server, with one endpoint only and every call I expect to receive should be from one source only.
This source signs their package before sending it to my server.
I want to implement this signature validation on my server for any call I receive.
Since any call should be from this expected source I do not want to validate the signature in my handler itself but I want it to be clean and at middleware level. In this way, if one day I implement a new endpoint that the known client is allowed to call, I won't have to repeat the signature validation in the new handler/route because already happening at middleware level.

The problem I am having is that I do not how to error out at middleware level, in such a way that the call doesn't proceed further to the next step in case the validation fails.
What I am having so far.

in `main.go`

```
server.Router.Use(verifySignatureMiddleware) // server.Router is my Router *chi.Mux
server.Router.Post("/", dummyHandler.ServeHTTP)
```

then my `verifySignatureMiddleware` is defined as follow:

```
func verifySignatureMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
      // print error and make sure that code execution stops here
    }
    
    
    isValid, err = otherLogicForSignatureValidation()
    if err != nil {
        // print error and make sure that code execution stops here
    }

    if isValid == false {
        // print error and make sure that code execution stops here
    }

    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

}

Thus, there are different levels at which the middleware can fail and I would like in any of those cases the handling of the http request stops and logs the error.

Comment: Please define what precisely do you mean by "handling of the http request stops"? What happens with the client's request? I mean, on the surface, what you're after looks like a job for `panic(http.ErrAbortHandler)` but it has its specific repercussions like tearing down the TCP connection on which the request has been served.

Comment: you are right, what I mean is that the server still needs to live of course but the a proper http code gets returned back. If something goes wrong with reading the content of the http call then the server returns a 500 for example. If a validation fails then a 401. What I mean for stopping is that the http request doesn't get handled any further than the failure point.

Comment: Use `return` to terminate the middleware function.

Comment: OK, I would then introduce custom ("sentinel") errors and would panic with them, while catching them in the top-level handler. On the other hand, I do not quite see the problem: it looks like that, on any "level", "the next" handler won't be called if one of the error-handling paths has been taken, and the chain (stack) of handlers will just effectively "unwind"–back to the top-level one. Provided that at the point an error was spotted you report the error to the client, I fail to see what's wrong with just returning form the current handler, and then all the way back.

Comment: Well, maybe it's just as simple as suggested by mkopriva: that is, you just need to do something like `reportError(w); return` in every body of `if err != nil` conditions. `reportError` is supposed to be a helper function which sets an appropriate HTTP status code in the ResponseWriter and then writes the error (in an expected format) to the client.

Comment: It was indeed as simple as a `return` statement that stops the cascaded execution of middlewares (in conjunction with writing a response code in the `ResponseWriter` of course) that made the deal. Thank youb both @mkopriva @kostix